# PowerShell - how to set mailbox to a user in Exchange 2003 remotely from a Win2008 server

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

in my company we still have Exchange 2003 with a MS domain 2003. I also have some member servers 2008 and I would like to run some powershell scripts from this last server.
I need to create a user which have 3 different email addreses SMTP.
I run this code to create the user

> New-ADUser -SamAccountName $adpsID -Name $fmbName -Description
>   $fmbName -DisplayName $fmbName -UserPrincipalName $adpsID
>   -EmailAddress $fmbNameEmail -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "!$%&DF45DFG_" -Force) -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -Path $pathFMB

and I tried this to add an extra email...

> Set-Mailbox -identity $fmbName -EmailAddresses -Description
>   "SMTP:$($fmbNameEmail)@$($domainFQDN)"

I get the following error:

> Set-Mailbox : The term 'Set-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

searching in google I found how to query the exchange 2003 usin WMI object but I couldnt find how to add mailboxes with WMI.

is it possible? is there any way to do so?

thanks a lot in advance.
Jose

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange Management Shell was first introduced in Exchange 2007 so all the scripts you have for 2007,2010,2013 will not work on 2013 you will need to start from scratch.

On Exchange 2003 the Exchange API to use for Management is CDOEXM (important if you want to Mail-Enable objects) this is Com library you get when you install the exchange 2003 system management tools  .Or you can modify the Directory objects directly using LDAP via ADSI. WMI on 2003 is useful if you want to access management information like Mailbox sizes or MessageTracking logs or you need to reconnect a disconnected Mailbox.

Cheers
Glen